# C# winforms designer postion doesnt match debug position

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a UI for my C# code, sadly the positioning of the elements from the WinForms designer doesn't match the debugged version.

Does anyone know what causes the misplacement?

Screenshot WinForms designer:
[image]

Screenshot debug:
[image]

Comment: I can't see any difference

Comment: Are you using a third party tab control component? Maybe it's designer support is lacking. Or, if it is data-driven the designer is not going to query the database or whatever data store.

Comment: The diffs is that debug shows the tabs. Check whether they are set to be hidden in runtime?

Comment: The tabs are there in design mode only on purpose. At runtime, you use the text links above

Comment: @NineBerry: Do you know what control/framework this is?